# Django-restframework - use the same value on differents fields

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm building an API using Django-restframework.
**models.py**

```
class Researches(models.Model):
    research_id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
```

I would like to use the same value on two differents fileds, like:

```
[
    {
        "research_id": 1,
        "id": 1
    },
]
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but why? You shouldn't duplicate data like this, especially the primary key.

Comment: I know, but the project need like that =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do something like this:

```
class ResearchesSerializer(
    serializers.ModelSerializer
):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(
        source="research_id", read_only=True
    )
    class Meta:
        model = Researches
        fields = (
            "research_id",
            "id",

        )
```

for ref: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-fields-explicitly

Comment: Only ```"__all__"``` isn't enough? It's a lot of fields to write on field one by one hehehe

Comment: you can try

fields = [f.name for f in Researches._meta.get_fields()] + ["id"]

Comment: @null92 The main point here is that you can specify a field in the serializer that isn't on the model. Personally, I would use the default `id` field in the model and databaase then add `resource_id` as another field on the serializer similarly to how this answer does with `id`.

Comment: Also, you don't need to specify `fields` if you want all fields.